# JPA: Possible to add additional JOIN constraint on @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables 'account_pools' and 'accounts' , basically looking like this

```
CREATE TABLE account_pools ( 
    pool_id bigint PRIMARY KEY 
);

CREATE TABLE accounts ( 
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY, 
    pool_id bigint NOT NULL,
    deleted boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    username text NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY pool_id REFERENCES account_pools(pool_id)
);
```

The 'accounts' table is historized, so when the user edits an account, the current row/version is marked with "deleted=true" and a new row containing the user's changes is inserted.

The application layer doesn't need to know about the historization so I'd like my AccountPool entity to *only* fetch the accounts that are not deleted ; something similar to

```
@Entity
public class AccountPool {

     //...stuff
     @OneToMany
     @MAGIC_ANNOTATION( restriction = "deleted=false" )
     private List<Account> accounts;
}
```

Possible solutions I came up with so far:

1. Use @PostLoad to populate the 'accounts' collection , this works when using Hibernate as a JPA provider but violates the JPA API
   contract that states that entity listeners/callbacks must not invoke
   EntityManager methods (see
   https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html)
2. Mark the 'accounts' field as @Transient and manually wrap all my methods that fetch AccountPool instances from the database to
   explicitly populate the 'accounts' collection afterwards

Solution 1.) works but is violating the JPA API contract

Solution 2.) works but is really error prone = breaks whenever somebody adds a new method that fetches AccountPool instances from the DB but forgets to manually populate the 'accounts collection afterwards

Did I miss something ?

Comment: btw, I'm using JDK8 , JPA 2.1 and Hibernate 5.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the non-JPA, Hibernate specific `@Where` annotation to filter the collection.

See section 2.4.6.1

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/

```
@Entity
public class AccountPool {

     @OneToMany
     @Where( clause = "deleted='false'" )
     private List<Account> accounts;
}
```

Alternately, for a JPA compliant solution you could create a DB view which filters the deleted items and map your `Account` entity to that.